# What can I use instead of "in case"?

Tags: expression-choice

What expression can I use instead of "in case" in the following sentence?

In other words, **in case** the plants suffer from a small period of water stress, plants grown on the new substrates will not decrease their capacity to conserve water.

Thank you

Comment: ‘In the event that’ is possible.  But what is wrong with ‘if’?.  Or, for that matter, ‘in case’?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to say.

Comment: "even if" the plants suffer from a small period ...

Comment: *When* also works. You're going to have to be more specific about what you want. Otherwise, we can simply list a whole series of possibilities.

Comment: Your clauses donl’t go together.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the word "should".
"In other words, *should* the plants suffer from a small period of water stress, plants grown on the new substrates will not decrease their capacity to conserve water."

Comment: Hi Robyn Simpson, Welcome to EL&U.SE. Your answer was flagged as low quality due to its length and content. Please provide more detailed answers. Use attributed references whenever possible to strengthen your response. Review the Help Center (? icon) menu in the UR corner of the page for guidance.

Comment: +1 Because you answered with something I hadn't thought of. Also, I saw nothing wrong with your answer; it matches the quality of the question . . .